# $2\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)>\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1 a_2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}}$

Tags: inequality

> For positive reals $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ Prove that the following inequality holds $$2\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)>\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1 a_2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}}$$

---

**Attempt:** By AM-GM, we get $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k}}{k} \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_k}}$$ So we are left to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k}}{k}< 2(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n})$$ We will try to prove this with induction. Assume the inequality is true for $n$, now we have to show it's true for $n+1$. After using the hypothesis and cancelling out some terms, we are left to prove $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{a_k}}{n+1}<\frac{2}{a_{n+1}}$$ And I'm stuck here, also I doubt if we can continue with induction at all. But other than induction, I'm not able to find any suitable manipulation or relations to continue the problem either. I'm looking for some hints that will guide to a potential solution. Thanks.
**Edit:** The induction that I tried doesn't work, and as discussed in the comments, substituting $a_i= \frac{1}{b_i}$ and improving the coefficient might help

Comment: Your induction won't work, since it obviously won't hold if $a_{n+1}$ is large, but $a_i$ are really small.  (Naive induction on the statement won't work either).

Comment: @CalvinLin to be honest I also "felt" that the last inequality won't work ( because on on the RHS we dont have any terms related to $a_1,...a_n$) but other than that, as I mentioned before I am not getting any other idea

Comment: 1/ The bound is very loose, so there are lots of things to try. 2/ Work on the small cases, esp $n =3$. In fact, show that $ a + \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt[3]{abc} \leq  4/3 (a+b+c)$ which improves the coefficient. Think about to extrapolate from there.

Comment: @CalvinLin what does it mean to "improving the coefficient"? Also how do you know if a bound is loose(knowing the nature of a bound may turn out very useful sometimes)?

Comment: (Side note: Replace $1/a_i $ with $b_i$ simplifies the expression) Instead of bounding by $2(a+b+c)$, I bounded it by $4/3 (a+b+c)$. I improved the coefficient from 2 to 4/3 (for n = 3). This suggests that if we can prove a stronger version of the inequality, maybe induction can work as we increase the coefficient towards 2.

Comment: I couldn't get my idea to work, so this might be harder than I made it sound like. $\quad$ Are you aware of a [similar result involving the RHS](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975630)?

Comment: @CalvinLin No I was not aware of such a result? Do we apply it here? Also I arrived at this problem while trying to solve another problem (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2935299p26266790). I applied AM GM to get that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{a_1+\ldots+a_k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{a_1 a_2 \ldots a_k}}$$ from which I arrived at the problem mentioned in the post ( I thought adding a background of this problem might be helpful)

Comment: Is it true that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_1 +b_2 + \cdots + b_k}{k}< 2(b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_n)$ for $b_2 = b_3 = \cdots = b_n = 0$? $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is unbounded, right?

Comment: @RiverLi yes, i have made the substitution, but I'm not able to prove it yet

Comment: I found that for $n \le 4$, the problem was discussed in 2013. For example, for $n=4$, it is true that $b_1 + \sqrt{b_1b_2} + \sqrt[3]{b_1b_2b_3} + \sqrt[4]{b_1b_2b_3b_4} \le \frac{10}{7} (b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4)$.

Comment: @RiverLi can you send me the link to the discussion?

Comment: For $n=3$, it is Slovenia 2012. See: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h549604p3188758

Comment: @RiverLi this is what Calvin Lin said as well in the above comments. Now, does the inequality with coefficient 4/3 holds true for any $n$? Can we somehow verify this? As Calvin mentioned, improving the coefficient might help us proceeding with induction.

Comment: For $n=4$, see: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h549731p3189705

Comment: @Diff_Equations It is unusual that you don't use $a_1 + \sqrt{a_1a_2} \le 2(a_1 + a_2)$ but $\frac{1}{a_1} + \cdots$.

Comment: This is false for $n$ large enough and 2 should be replaced by $e$: see Carleman Inequality in Wikipedia.